# Update-Set for a Date type not processing query part correctly in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to extract a text date into a date type field and change the format from `yyyymmdd` to `ddmmyyyy` in the process. I have set up a simple select statement checking that the dates are valid and if not setting a default date and this worked fine, no bad dates.

```
SELECT
IIf(isdate(Format(Left([EffectiveDate],10),"dd/mm/yyyy")),Format(Left([EffectiveDate],10),"dd/mm/yyyy"),#01/01/1900#) AS Expr1
FROM Relationships;
```

But when I embed this exact same select statement in an Update Set Query:

```
UPDATE Relationships 
SET MSDate = IIf(isdate(Format(Left([EffectiveDate],10),"dd/mm/yyyy")),Format(Left([EffectiveDate],10),"dd/mm/yyyy"),#01/01/1900#);
```

the dates are formed as `mmddyyyy` and not `ddmmyyyy` as the select query does.

Interestingly, when I tried to change the format type to "long date"

```
UPDATE Relationships 
SET MSDate = IIf(isdate(Format(Left([EffectiveDate],10),"long date")),Format(Left([EffectiveDate],10),"dd/mm/yyyy"),#01/01/1900#);
```

I got the default `01/01/1900` result suggesting what was extracted was not a valid date. By the way, just using the query in a Select statement worked just fine.

I can't help thinking that something is happening in the conversion to date type. I even tried to do DateValue on the query but still no joy.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `Left([EffectiveDate],10)`, I assume that the text field actually contains `yyyy-mm-dd` (the ISO format).

You should leave the string in this format (Access understands ISO and US format `mm/dd/yyyy` best), and convert it with the `CDate()` function.

```sql
UPDATE Relationships 
SET MSDate = IIf(IsDate(Left([EffectiveDate],10)), 
                  CDate(Left([EffectiveDate],10)), 
                  #1900-01-01#);
```

Comment: Hi Andre ... thank you for this...sorry to be bit tardy getting back...essentially I want the MSDate to be formatted as ddmmyyyy. When I try your suggestion above MSDate is in mmddyyyy form. I tried to insert the Cdate function into my format statement like this: UPDATE Relationships SET MSDate = IIf(isdate(Format(Cdate(Left([EffectiveDate],10)),"dd/mm/yyyy")),Format(Cdate(Left([EffectiveDate],10)),"dd/mm/yyyy"),#1/1/1900#); But no change...yet off course the formatting works if I'm just doing a select.....and yes the source field is in yyyymmdd format

Comment: A date field just stores a date, internally as a number. It has no intrinsic format, except the one you define in table design or in a query or in a form field. -- You don't need the `Format` in your UPDATE query, only the `CDate`.

Comment: ok I see what you mean .... so if I have code that requires processing a date stored in MSDate that is presented to it in ddmmyyyy form then I have to format that on the way out before the code processes it, rather than the way in?

Comment: @LaurenceLockLee: e-xact-ly! :)